# Why does the following haskell code for creating a Foldable instance of Tree result in infinite recursion?

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree

I am trying to write a Foldable instance of the following Tree class I created:

```
data Tree a b = Tree b a [Tree a b]
```

But I wanted to operate on type 'a' in the definition therefore I made a wrapper data type the flips the types in Tree:

```
data FlipTree a b = FlipTree (Tree b a)
```

Now to write the actual definition I came up with the following:

```
instance Foldable (FlipTree a) where
  foldr f x (FlipTree (Tree _ s [])) = (f s x)
  foldr f x (FlipTree (Tree _ s children)) =
              let updated_x = (f s x)
                  tqs = (map (\n -> FlipTree n) children) in
              foldl (foldr f) updated_x tqs
```

But this results in infinite recursion when foldr is called. I have spent two days and have not been able to figure out the thing that I am doing wrong?

this is [lpaste](http://lpaste.net/) link to [the code file](http://lpaste.net/154546). I isolated the code as much as I could. This is another [file1](http://lpaste.net/154547) which is read to run the code using the command:

runghc code.hs 30000000.0 20000.0 < file1.txt

Comment: I don't seem to get infinite loops on test data. What are your looping values?

Comment: When you have an error/unexpected result you should *always* post 1) The inputs you are using 2a) The error you get or 2b) the unexpected result *and* what result you did expect.   Btw: your second equation is simply `= foldl (foldr f) (f s x) $ map FlipTree children` which is more coincise, and I believe even clearer than using a `let` and splitting that simple expression...

Comment: Hey @AndrásKovács, Thanks for your response. Can I share a .hs file with you?

Comment: @MuhammadAli: use [lpaste](http://lpaste.net/), [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), [github-gist](https://gist.github.com/) or [ideone](http://ideone.com/) for sharing code files. The last has the advantage of even running your test program, so you can be sure the behaviour is actually reproducible!

Comment: @AndrásKovács. I added some links. Please have a look.

Comment: @Bakuriu. I added some links. Please have a look.

Comment: You could simply copy&paste that code into the question. If it's not thousands of lines it's perfectly fine. Even better would be if you tried to remove the code that isn't needed to replicate the problem, so as to minimize the code required.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer (the questions premise of infinite looping doesn't seem to be correct) but stylistic advice – too long to comment.

First, you probably want to make this a `newtype` (there's no reason to have an extra layer of laziness).

```
newtype FlipTree a b = FlipTree (Tree b a)
```

Second, for an easier understandable solution it tends IMO to be preferrable to implement `foldMap` instead of `foldr`; it makes the semantics clearer. There are multiple ways to fold over this structure, the most reasonable seems

```
  foldMap f (FlipTree (Tree _ s [])) = f s
  foldMap f (FlipTree (Tree _ s children))
             = f s <> foldMap (foldMap f . FlipTree) children
```

where the outer `foldMap` folds over the list of children, using again `foldMap` for `FlipTree`s as the folding-mapping. Now, if you want to manually translate this to the `foldr` equivalent, you basically just need to thread through the argument.

```
  foldr f x (FlipTree (Tree _ s children))
             = f s . flip (foldr $ flip (foldr f) . FlipTree) children $ x
```

Now, possibly that instance doesn't actually give the desired behaviour, so please *tell us* how you want it to behave!

Comment: hey leftaroundabout thanks for your response. I have added the links in the description. Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the definition is 100% correct. The unwanted behaviour was being caused by the rest of the code. But thanks anyway to the stackoverflow community for always being there.